# -bash: syntax error near excpected token `('

Tags: bash

I try to start a java application with a bunch of arguments but I get the error in the title (GNU bash 4.2.45). On windows it works fine. With removing some arguments I checked which one produced the error and if I remove the following argument the application will start:

```
java -jar jarFile.jar --spring.activemq.broker-url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?timeout=5000
```

Has it something to do with the colons? I tried to escape them with `\:` but it doesn't help.

Comment: `On windows it works fine`.  How does this matter? Windows is using a different shell.

Comment: @hek2mgl I know, it should only say that I was working before on windows with the same arguments and now I changed to linux with bash and now it won't work, but I had no idea why.

Comment: Because it is a different *language*?

Comment: I know its different but I don't know what was different. The question is also solvable if that sentence would not be in the question, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bash is telling you, the `(` is causing a syntax error. I would suggest putting single quotes around the argument:

```
--spring.activemq.broker-url='failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?timeout=5000'
```

Strings within single quotes are interpreted literally, which means that among other things, `(` won't be interpreted by the shell. In the shell, `(` is used to open a subshell, which is invalid here.